# Controls inside a Usercontrol don't get initialized if it's in a Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a situation where I'm using some markup in 2 places on a page, one of which is in a repeater. The one in the repeater is not initializing its child controls; they're staying null.

Default.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="nestedcontroltest._Default" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="a" Namespace="nestedcontroltest" Assembly="nestedcontroltest" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptLetters" OnItemDataBound="rptLetters_ItemDataBound">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <a:MyControl runat="server" ID="ctrlMyControl"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </body>
</html>
```

Default.aspx.cs:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rptLetters.DataSource = new[] { "a", "b", "c" };
        rptLetters.DataBind();
    }

    public void rptLetters_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        var ctrlMyControl = (MyControl)e.Item.FindControl("ctrlMyControl");
        ctrlMyControl.Text = e.Item.DataItem.ToString();
    }
}
```

MyControl.ascx:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MyControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="nestedcontroltest.MyControl" %>
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlContent">
    <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="ltlText"/>
</asp:Panel>
```

MyControl.ascx.cs:

```
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ltlText.Text = Text;
    }
}
```

When I try to load this, I get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." - apparently ltlText is null.

How can I get my UserControl to initialize properly?

Comment: If your debugger is coming at `ltlText.Text` then your control is getting initialized for sure, but your `ltlText` is not getting init. So problem is in your user control I guess.

Comment: user controls don't have methods like `Page_Load` but have simply `OnLoad(EventArgs e)` method so be aware to use Page methods in your controls it's sometimes hard to debug why some control is null

Comment: Have you registered a reference to user control, like: <%@ Register src="MyControl.ascx" tagname="MyControl" tagprefix="a" %> ?

Comment: Hi guys, I've updated Default.aspx to include the `@Register` directive.

Comment: Thanks yogi, you're right, the repeater was a red herring. It turns out the problem was in my `@Register` directive; registering by namespace and assembly doesn't seem to result in the control being initialized, but registering the control by name works. Now to see if I can answer my own question..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the answer:

1. The repeater had nothing to do with the problem.
2. In Default.aspx, I needed to register the control by name rather than by namespace.

   ```
   <%@ Register TagPrefix="a" Namespace="nestedcontroltest" Assembly="nestedcontroltest" %>
   ```

   Needs to be changed to

   ```
   <%@ Register TagPrefix="a" TagName="MyControl" Src="~/MyControl.ascx" %>
   ```

And then the control gets initialized properly, even when it's in the repeater. Perhaps a bug in ASP.net, or perhaps I needed to use the full assembly name? Regardless, thanks for all your help guys.

Comment: I shall never forget this! Thanks Chris!

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not add Bind or Eval expressions in your markup, could it be that e.Item.DataItem is null, rather than ltlText?

What does the debugger say?

Comment: Nope, the debugger is saying e.Item.DataItem is "a", then "b", then "c", like you'd expect. The exception is definitely on the line `ltlText.Text = Text;` and ltlText is definitely null.